# Prism v4 for windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, prism-4

Dear all.
I am a newbie in Prism. I found the [Hands On Lab](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) which tells me the steps to create a Prism application on windows, which is good.
Now I am trying to find the same lab to create a Prism application on Windows Phone 7 but I haven't found anything.
If you know about this, please tell me.
Thank you so much.

Binh Nguyen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prism v4 includes signed assemblies for Windows Phone 7, which are a subset of the Prism and Prism.Interaction libraries. They include support for the Prism event aggregator, commands, view model, and interaction request, but does not include the Unity dependency injection container.

For more information about using Prism for Windows Phone 7, check out the excellent [Windows Phone 7 Developer Guide](http://wp7guide.codeplex.com/) community site, which includes a reference applicaion.